# How can I create a CarrierWave version from an outside url (zencoder or blitline) without any internal processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, carrierwave

In other words: Is it possible to create CarrierWave versions without processing and then assign them different url locations?

CarrierWave makes creating and accessing versions easy when you do the processing on your own server, but in certain cases I'd like services outside my app to process images and video.

For example, you can send an Amazon S3 URL to ZenCoder and instruct it to create two smaller video files. One optimized for the web and one for mobile. The following tutorial does a great job explaining how to assign **one** zencoder url to the mounted attribute. http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/video-encoding-with-uploadify-carrierwave-and-zencoder

I'd like to figure out how to assign the encoded web video url to a ":web" version and the encoded mobile video url to a ":mobile" version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you designate versions in your CarrierWave uploader class without any processing, CarrierWave will create a copy of the movie with the version prefix.

Specify an empty version:

```
version :mobile
```

Carrierwave creates two files:

> path/example.mov
>
> path/mobile_example.mov

To encode only the mobile version, pass Zencoder the link via:

```
my_object.url(:mobile)
```